# How to loop through a directory or list of files with a wildcard in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to anonymize my Apache logs after 7 days and actually I have already some trouble to write the skript for anonymizing.

My script replaces the 3 first digit with `X` and it works properly when running a log file in the same directory as the bash script.

But I would like to use wildcard for anonymise all logs from my subdomains, like this:

```
./anonym /basedir/*/logs/access.log
```

But this doesn't work properly.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "$line"  | sed s/./X/1 | sed s/./X/2 |sed s/./X/3
done < "$1">"/tmp/$1"

mv "/tmp/$1" "$1"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is the rest of your script?

Answer (score 1):

To perform the same actions for multiple files, you need to wrap your code in a loop, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=/tmp/anon.$$

for path; do
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "$line" | sed -e s/./X/1 -e s/./X/2 -e s/./X/3
    done < "$path" > "$tmpfile"

    mv "$tmpfile" "$path"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you write to the same file eventually, just use `sed -i` (it's not POSIX though). From [`man 1 sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

> `-i[SUFFIX]`, `--in-place[=SUFFIX]`
>   edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied). The default operation mode is to break symbolic and hard links. This can be changed with `--follow-symlinks` and `--copy`.

Additionally the following sed expression may replace your three separate ones: `s/.../XXX/`. It's not entirely equivalent in general, maybe you'd like to improve it. Anyway, using `-i` all you need to do is:

```
sed -i `s/.../XXX/` /basedir/*/logs/access.log
```